# ng-repeat: access key-value pair in angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, meteor

I want to access the key value pair of an object.I tried so many times changing name values etc.. But the same problem exists.

I have a mongo collection like this:

```
{
"_id" : "GdfaHPoT7FXW78awi",
"name" : "todo",
"highlight" : [ 
    {
        "status" : "upcoming"
    }, 
    {
        "status" : "overdue"
    }, 
    {
        "status" : "today"
    }
]
```

}

my client side js looks like this

```
            self.subscribe('featureDetails', () => [], {
            onReady: function() {
                self.helpers({ /// helpers to make it reactive
                    features: () => {
                        let settings = SaFeature.find({}).fetch();
                        //var subSettings = []
                        return {
                            settings
                        };
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

and my html like this

```
    <div layout="row" ng-repeat="list in dynamicSettingsCtrl.features.settings">
    <fieldset class="standard">
          <md-checkbox aria-label="Checkbox 1" ng-model="moreOptions">
                <p>{{list.name}}</p>
            </md-checkbox>
        <div layout-gt-sm="row">


            <div ng-if="moreOptions">
                <form>
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                        <label>Set Limt</label>
                        <input ng-model="maxLimit">
                    </md-input-container>
                    <md-input-container class="md-block" ng-repeat="(key, value) in list.highlight" flex-gt-sm>
                        <label>{{key}}:{{value}}</label>
                        <input ng-model="upLimit">
                    </md-input-container>
           </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

If you look at my html, I want to display the key value pair as status:upcoming. but what I am getting is 0:{"status":"upcoming"}.
How can I get the exact key value pair?
Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
<md-input-container class="md-block" ng-repeat="highlight in list.highlight" flex-gt-sm>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in highlight">
        <label>{{key}}:{{value}}</label>
        <input ng-model="upLimit">
    </div>
</md-input-container>
```